# What is good practise for getting resource/collection models?

Tags: magento-1.9, programming, best-practice

Which one is more correct:
 **Mage::getResourceModel()** or
**Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()**

I always use the first method unless I already have a model that I can call the getCollection on. I'm just wondering if there are any advantages/disadvantages to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The methods `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::getResource()` and `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::getCollection()` are just handy shortcuts if you want to get the resource model or collection for an existing model instance.

They eventually call `Mage::getResourceModel()`, so if you don't already have an instantiated model, the more straightforward way to instantiate a collection or resource model is to use `Mage::getResourceModel()` directly. **The result is always the same.**

Answer (score 5):

**Mage::getModel()**

Mage::getModel() will create a new instance of an object each time even such object exists in configuration.

Example

```
$product1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

$product1 and $product2 both have different instant of same object and also occupy different memory

**Mage::getResourceModel()**

As far as I know, all collections in Magento are resource models. They are instantiated by

```
Mage::getResourceModel()
```

or

```
Mage::getModel()->getCollection()
```

It doesn't really matter which function you use; the latter one simply calls the first one. The Magento team simply chose to make collections part of the resource, probably because collections need to query the database a lot. Usually, you will not have to call `Mage::getResourceModel()` for anything else than collections.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153973/magento-when-to-use-magegetresourcemodel-and-magegetmodel)